# Usage of spec.js file in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

This might sound a stupid question, but I want to know its answer. What is the **spec.js** file in **AngularJS** and what is its use? Is it used for *testing* purpose?

EDIT- Below is the code of file **phone-detail.component.spec.js**

```
'use strict';

describe('phoneDetail', function() {

  // Load the module that contains the `phoneDetail` component before each test
  beforeEach(module('phoneDetail'));

  // Test the controller
  describe('PhoneDetailController', function() {
    var $httpBackend, ctrl;
    var xyzPhoneData = {
      name: 'phone xyz',
      images: ['image/url1.png', 'image/url2.png']
    };

    beforeEach(inject(function($componentController, _$httpBackend_, $routeParams) {
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
      $httpBackend.expectGET('phones/xyz.json').respond(xyzPhoneData);

      $routeParams.phoneId = 'xyz';

      ctrl = $componentController('phoneDetail');
    }));

    it('should fetch the phone details', function() {
      jasmine.addCustomEqualityTester(angular.equals);

      expect(ctrl.phone).toEqual({});

      $httpBackend.flush();
      expect(ctrl.phone).toEqual(xyzPhoneData);
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: if i was to blindly guess, it might be a test helper that helps the tests run. Post the code and we can tell you more.

Comment: @derp I am following the turorial on AngularJS's site [https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) and I'm adding the code of one of the **spec.js** file ( _phone-detail.component.spec.js_ )

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use of spec.js is for writing you unit test cases for your angular application.
We write test cases in angular using Jasmine & Karma.

**Jasmine** is a Behavior Driven Development testing framework for JavaScript. It does not rely on browsers, DOM, or any JavaScript framework. Thus it's suited for websites, Node.js projects, or anywhere that JavaScript can run.

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine

**Karma** is essentially a tool which spawns a web server that executes source code against test code for each of the browsers connected. The results of each test against each browser are examined and displayed via the command line to the developer such that they can see which browsers and tests passed or failed.

https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/index.html

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful :)

Comment: That was helpful. I am newbie to AngularJS and have to write AngularJS application that needs unit testing. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

*Question* - **What is the *spec.js* file in AngularJS ?**

*Answer* - **AngularJS** uses *Jasmine* as a testing framework and tests written in *Jasmine* are called **specs**. Filename written related to *Jasmine* must be **.spec.ts**, the filename extension convention is adhered by configuration of 
*karma*( the test runner tool ).

---

*Question* - **what is its use? Is it used for testing purpose?**

*Answer* - *Karma* the test runner gets the specifications for testing from this file. yes, it is used for testing :)

---

**Reference** https://angular.io/guide/testing